# I forked the repo for a Github Pages that I liked, but my fork will not load

Tags: github, fork, github-pages

I am a total programming noob and assume I'm missing something basic.

I forked this repo: https://github.com/colinmorris/tour-of-heroes

Here is the author's page for that repo: https://colinmorris.github.io/tour-of-heroes/

My fork: https://github.com/SmallFryHero/tour-of-heroes

My page based on that fork: https://smallfryhero.github.io/tour-of-heroes/

My page does not load.

I deployed the Github Pages using the gh-pages branch and from the /root folder.

I imported the code into a different web editor, CodeSandBox, and I can get it to run there along with my changes.

What do I need to fix to get it to run on my Github Pages? I added a readme to get the page to build. It seems to be deployed, but doesn't get past the "loading..." step.

Thanks for any help! Sorry for the total noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that GitHub Pages, by default, use a static site generator called [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) under the hood. It basically converts a set of Markdown files into HTML (and provides templating, themes, plugins, and more).

In the case of your repo, which consists exclusively of static assets, Jekyll doesn't do much, but it *does* exclude the `node_modules` directory (see [logs](https://github.com/SmallFryHero/tour-of-heroes/actions/runs/3976044177/jobs/6816280605#step:4:35)), which leads to the scripts in there being unavailable to the deployed page.

To fix this, you can indicate that you wish to skip any Jekyll processing and just upload the files as they are; to do so, add an empty file `.nojekyll` to the root directory in the `gh-pages` branch, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#troubleshooting-publishing-from-a-branch).

The repo from which you forked was last deployed multiple years ago, and I suspect the Jekyll default configuration back then didn't exclude `node_modules` yet.